# Read Variable length string in a file using SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm, asic

Suppose I have variable length string as below:

```
Write <Address> <Data0> <Data1> <Data2>
Read <Address>
Write <Address> <Data0>
Write <Address> <Data0> <Data1> <Data2> <Data3>
```

How do I read in SystemVerilog or Verilog using file operations. I know to read when there is fixed length of text

```
integer file    = $fopen(file_name,"r");
code = $fgets(line, file);
code = $sscanf(line, "%s %h %h %h", txn_type, Address, Data[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$sscanf` when the number of fields is not fixed, as long as you supply the maximum possible number of fields.  The return value placed in `code` indicates the actual number of arguments scanned. So just create a dummy list of arguments and copy the ones provided by the line